# Script Not Operating Independent of Other Scripts

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have set up a rough script (new to this) to automate some data entry that I have to do consistently. I build a UI with checkboxes and have data fill into the sheet based on the responses to the checks. It all works correctly for one product. The problem is that I have duplicated this for other products. When recreated for a second product, I have to rename the function in the second script to "BUILDUI2" in order to see the correct options display (otherwise it displays the options from the previous script). Then, even though I see the correct check boxes, the responses to the check boxes are based off of the first script created. So on the second product, selecting the second checkbox inserts the data specified in the original BuildUI script that is tied to the other product rather than the data shown under BuildUI2.

These are independent scripts activated by separate push buttons on the sheet.

Any insight on how to get the second (and third, and fourth) scripts to read the correct information?

Product 1 Script:

```
  function BuildUI() {
  //create the application itself
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(160).setWidth(250);
  app.setTitle("Options");

  //create panels and add them to the UI
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  //create a text box
  var check1 = app.createCheckBox("Safety Aprons");
  check1.setName('CheckBox1');

  var check2 = app.createCheckBox("Standard Trash Racks (1)");
  check2.setName('CheckBox2');

  var check3 = app.createCheckBox("Standard Trash Racks (2) ");
  check3.setName('CheckBox3');

  var check4 = app.createCheckBox("Plate Style Trash Racks (1)");
  check4.setName('CheckBox4');

  var check5 = app.createCheckBox("Plate Style Trash Racks (2) ");
  check5.setName('CheckBox5');   

  var check6 = app.createCheckBox("6:1 Safety Grates (1)");
  check6.setName('CheckBox6');

  var check7 = app.createCheckBox("6:1 Safety Grates (2)");
  check7.setName('CheckBox7');

  //create a submit button
  var button = app.createButton('Done');

  //add the text box and the button to the panel
  panel.add(check1);
  panel.add(check2);
  panel.add(check3);
  panel.add(check4);
  panel.add(check5); 
  panel.add(check6);
  panel.add(check7);
  panel.add(button);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler("submitButton");
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel); 

  //add the panel to the application
  app.add(panel);

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
  }

  function submitButton(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  if(e.parameter.CheckBox1 == 'true') {


  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = lastrow-4; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
  var row = values[i];
  if (row[2] == 'R012M-BAM' || row[2] == 'R012M-BAF') {
  sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
  rowsDeleted++;}
  } 
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("R012M-BSAF6");
  sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("1");
  sheet.getRange(lastrow+2,3).setValue("R012M-BSAM6");
  sheet.getRange(lastrow+2,5).setValue("1");
  }

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox2 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00092");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("1");
  } 

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox3 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00092");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("2");
  }     

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox4 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00094");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("1");
  } 

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox5 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00094");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("2");
  }     

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox6 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00095");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("1");
  }  

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox7 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00095");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("2");
  }    

  return app.close();
  }
```

Product 2 Script:

```
  function BuildUI2() {
  //create the application itself
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(225).setWidth(250);
  app.setTitle("Options");

  //create panels and add them to the UI
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();

  //create a text box
  var check1 = app.createCheckBox("Safety Aprons");
  check1.setName('CheckBox1');

  var check2 = app.createCheckBox("Pipe Style Trash Racks (1)");
  check2.setName('CheckBox2');

  var check3 = app.createCheckBox("Pipe Style Trash Racks (2) ");
  check3.setName('CheckBox3');

  var check4 = app.createCheckBox("Plate Style Trash Racks (1)");
  check4.setName('CheckBox4');

  var check5 = app.createCheckBox("Plate Style Trash Racks (2) ");
  check5.setName('CheckBox5');

  var check6 = app.createCheckBox("Bull Nose Style Trash Racks (1)");
  check6.setName('CheckBox6');

  var check7 = app.createCheckBox("Bull Nose Style Trash Racks (2) ");
  check7.setName('CheckBox7');

  var check8 = app.createCheckBox("6:1 Safety Grates (1)");
  check8.setName('CheckBox8');

  var check9 = app.createCheckBox("6:1 Safety Grates (2)");
  check9.setName('CheckBox9');

  //create a submit button
  var button = app.createButton('Done');

  //add the text box and the button to the panel
  panel.add(check1);
  panel.add(check2);
  panel.add(check3);
  panel.add(check4);
  panel.add(check5); 
  panel.add(check6);
  panel.add(check7);
  panel.add(check8);
  panel.add(check9);
  panel.add(button);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler("submitButton");
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel); 

  //add the panel to the application
  app.add(panel);

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
  }

  function submitButton(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  if(e.parameter.CheckBox1 == 'true') {


  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = lastrow-4; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
  var row = values[i];
  if (row[2] == 'R015M-BAM' || row[2] == 'R015M-BAF') {
  sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
  rowsDeleted++;}
  } 
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("R015M-BSAF6");
  sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("1");
  sheet.getRange(lastrow+2,3).setValue("R015M-BSAM6");
  sheet.getRange(lastrow+2,5).setValue("1");
  }

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox2 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00194");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("1");
  } 

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox3 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00194");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("2");
  }     

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox4 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00097");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("1");
  } 

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox5 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00097");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("2");
  }  

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox6 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00440");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("1");
  } 

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox7 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00440");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("2");
  }  

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox8 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00101");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("1");
  }  

  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if(e.parameter.CheckBox9 == 'true') 
  {sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,3).setValue("85-00101");
   sheet.getRange(lastrow+1,5).setValue("2");
  }    

  return app.close();
  }
```

Comment: If I may hazard a guess... it may be that your `submitButton` function has the same name in each file. If both files are being loaded into the same browser context, then one might be overwriting the other, so different buttons are calling the same `submitButton` function. I'm not a Google Apps Developer... just a guess. Could be totally off-base.

Comment: Well of course after trying forever to figure this out prior to posting the question, I think I have solved it minutes after posting it. By renaming the submitButton function to submitButton2 it works. I had tried this, but I missed renaming the call server handler and had only renamed the function.

Comment: by "product" you likely mean another source in the same project. thats not another "product".